# Deserialize json string to C# object in desktop application

Tags: c#, json, linq

```
{
    "autoRegUUID": null,
    "federationId": "nlk:1601014",
    "identityProvider": {
        "identityProvider": false,
        "identityProviderBusinessKey": "TINC",
        "identityProviderCode": "TINC",
        "identityProviderName": "Prime"
    },
    "loginName": "nlk",
    "primaryTenant": {
        "orgAddress": "13034 Ballne Corporate Pla",
        "orgCity": "Charlotte",
        "orgName": "Prime, Inc.",
        "orgState": "NC",
        "orgZip": "28277-198",
        "primaryOrganization": "NC0",
        "tin": null
    },
    "puid": "rreppsSsAPnPBgt",
    "userId": "rrepp",
    "userProfile": {
        "activeUser": true,
        "email": "Neil_Kirk@Prime.com",
        "firstName": "Neil",
        "internalUser": true,
        "jobTitle": "Portfolio Business Analyst",
        "lastLogin": "Jul 01, 2020, 15:23:14 PM",
        "lastName": "Kirk",
        "npi": null,
        "workPhone": "+14123995262",
        "workPhoneExt": null
    }
}
```

here is class

```
public class PremierUserDetails
    {
        public string autoRegUUID { get; set; }

        public string federationId { get; set; }

        public string loginName { get; set; }

        public string puid { get; set; }

        public string userId { get; set; }

        public List<identityProvider> Providers { get; set; }

        public List<primaryTenant> Tenant { get; set; }

        public List<userProfile> Profile { get; set; }
    }

    public class identityProvider 
    {
        public bool identityProviderAuthViaSSO { get; set; }
        public string identityProviderBusinessKey { get; set; }
        public string identityProviderCode { get; set; }
        public string identityProviderName { get; set; }

    }

    public class primaryTenant 
    {
        public string orgAddress { get; set; }
        public string orgCity { get; set; }
        public string orgName { get; set; }
        public string orgState { get; set; }
        public string orgZip { get; set; }
        public string primaryOrganization { get; set; }
        public string tin { get; set; }

    }

    public class userProfile 
    {
        public bool activeUser { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string firstName { get; set; }
        public string displayName { get; set; }
        public string internalUser { get; set; }
        public string jobTitle { get; set; }
        public string lastLogin { get; set; }
        public string lastName { get; set; }
        public string npi { get; set; }
        public string workPhone { get; set; }
        public string workPhoneExt { get; set; }
    }
```

..

```
var jsonData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PremierUserDetails>(json);
        PremierUserDetails user = new PremierUserDetails();
```

but the Providers, Tenant and Profile comes as null rest all are populated with value.

Comment: In the JSON, the property is called `primaryTenant` and it's a single value (not a list). You've got it as a List<primaryTenant>` with a property called `Tenant`. Same kind of problems for the other properties. Your JSON doesn't contain *any* lists.

Comment: As an aside, I'd strongly advise you to follow .NET naming conventions for your properties, and then specify the JSON naming via attributes. It's a lot cleaner than dealing with types like `primaryTenant` with properties like `orgAddress`.

Comment: Don't even need attributes, JSON deserializing can be made case insensitive!

Comment: There are websites like [this one](https://json2csharp.com/) where you can plug in your JSON and it will tell you what your DTO's should look like for that JSON.

Comment: I'd suggest using a conversion tool like https://app.quicktype.io/?l=csharp (There are others) to generate the backing models when dealing with JSON input like this. This will ensure that your type system matches the input exactly. You can tweak the namespace and attribute settings from there.

Answer (score 4):

Your "child" object(s) ... do-not/does-not seem to be json arrays.  (One giveaway is the lack of [] square brackets)

Try:

```
public class PremierUserDetails
    {
        public string autoRegUUID { get; set; }

        public string federationId { get; set; }

        public string loginName { get; set; }

        public string puid { get; set; }

        public string userId { get; set; }

        public identityProvider identityProvider{ get; set; }

        public primaryTenant primaryTenant { get; set; }

        public userProfile userProfile { get; set; }
    }
```

Now,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/names-of-classes-structs-and-interfaces

C# class names are PascalCase, .. so you want to handle your naming conventions differently.

You can see how to do that here:

https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonPropertyName.htm

Comment: You've named the properties "TheProvider", "TheTenant" and "TheProfile" where in the JSON they're "identityProvider", "primaryTenant" and "userProfile".

Comment: you'll need to change TheProvider to IdentityProvider, TheTenant to PrimaryTenant and TheProfile to UserProfile

Comment: Agreed.  Made the change and added Attribute Link.

Comment: You could also use a Json.NET attribute to rename it if you needed ([JsonProperty(PropertyName = "FooBar")]) , but I don't see a compelling reason why here.  One reason would be if the json element name violated C# naming conventions, like it started with a number or a period, for example.